# Object reference not set to an instance of an object while converting address to longitude and latitude

Tags: c#, google-maps

i was trying to convert address to longitude and latitude by this code..but i am getting exception like 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
System.NullReferenceException:Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

in the code

```
var address = "123 something st, somewhere";
var requestUri = string.Format("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address={0}&sensor=false", Uri.EscapeDataString(address));

var request = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
var response = request.GetResponse();
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());

var result = xdoc.Element("GeocodeResponse").Element("result");
var locationElement = result.Element("geometry").Element("location");
var lat = locationElement.Element("lat");
var lng = locationElement.Element("lng");
Response.Write(lat);
Response.Write(lng);
```

in the line

```
var locationElement = result.Element("geometry").Element("location");
```

someone please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're using a fake address to test...

I plugged your requestUrl and address (UrlEscaped) into Chrome and got this response:

```
<GeocodeResponse>
    <status>ZERO_RESULTS</status>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

Since it doesn't exist, there is no `<result>` element to work with; you need to add a check for this in your code, something like my code below...

Now, I tried it with a real address, and got [this XML (It's the white house)](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600%20Pennsylvania%20Ave%20NW,%20Washington,%20DC%2020500&sensor=false):

```
<GeocodeResponse>
    <status>OK</status>
    <result>...</result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

As you can see, you have a `<status>` element here also, with value "OK", which you can use:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
var status = xdoc.Root.Element("status").Value;

switch (status)
{
    case "ZERO_RESULTS":
        // oops! no location found!
        Response.Write("That address does not exist");
        break;
    case "OK":
        var result = xdoc.Element("GeocodeResponse").Element("result");
        var locationElement = result.Element("geometry").Element("location");
        var lat = locationElement.Element("lat");
        var lng = locationElement.Element("lng");
        Response.Write(lat);
        Response.Write(lng);                   
        break;
    default: 
        // handle other status
        break;
}
```

Comment: bro i  am doing a project that requires website developing in c#.can i get your help?.please can you give your any way of contact like mail id or fb. really need help bro

Comment: I can help you but it won't be cheap :)

Comment: It was a joke. I'm saying if you need that much help with a project, no one is going to do it for free. I suggest read C# books to learn the basics and when you get stuck keep asking questions here on SO.

Comment: Good luck dude. Don't forget to mark the answer which helped you the most as the accepted answer (check mark icon under the answer score) :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you get NULL in result or result.Element("geometry"). Check it in debugger mode please